# Looping a slice or using a mapping is better to retrieve an object

Tags: go

I have a slice which contains around 3000 bson objects. Every object has some nested mappings and one object has an average size of `4 kb`. In my code I have to be able to retrieve these objects based on their `uid` field fast as possible. My original plan was to write a function to simply loop through the original slice and check for the matching `uid` like `object["uid"] == uidToFind`. However now I believe it would be better creating one big mapping where the keys are using the `uid` field and the values using the corresponding object, somehow like this:

```
m := make(map[string]bson.M)
m["sample_UID_0"] = bsonObjects[0]
m["sample_UID_1"] = bsonObjects[1]
//... continue with the remaining 3000 objects...
```

My question is, should I favor this solution over looping through the original slice every time? As I don't have millions of objects, I assume it would be a better idea to keep important stuff in one globally available mapping and just simply access them with `m["sample_UID"]` rather than always loop through the whole slice.

Comment: Using a map is definitely the better idea if access time is critical and you don't mind the additional memory usage of storing the UID address or value twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond performance and memory usage there is one main difference between both solution, the way your map is defined can only contain one entry with the same id. Nothing prevents to have multiple times the same id in your array.

In general, if your array is sorted, you can use a dichotomic search which should not raise any visible difference with a search in an map, but you must keep your array sorted when adding new entries. So the benefit of this solution depends if your array is frequently modified. An array should use less memory than a map.

In your specific example, 3000 entries is not that much. Depending on the frequency of the search in data structure, it's not obvious you may notice any difference on the performance side. You may want to use benchmark to check that.

Comment: I ended up using a map. But will look after dichotomic search, great info! Big up!